# Is there a class for optimization problems with polynomial-time-computable bounds?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, optimization, complexity-classes

An optimization problem can be described by two functions $f$ and $g$, such that:

- $f$ is a binary predicate representing the constraints: $f(x,y)$ is True if the output $y$ is feasible for the input $x$;
- $g$ is an integer-valued function representing the objective value: $g(x,y)$ is the value of the output $y$ for the input $x$.

The pair $(f,g)$ represents the problem "Given the input $x$, find some $y$ that maximizes $g(x,y)$ subject to $f(x,y)$". Denote by $OPT(x)$ the value of the optimal solution for $x$.
The problem $(f,g)$ is *polynomial-time solvable* if $OPT(x)$ can be found in time polynomial in the length of $x$.

Define a problem $(f,g)$ as *polynomial-time boundable* if there are real-valued functions $MIN$ and $MAX$ such that, for every input $x$, $MIN(x)\leq OPT(x)\leq MAX(x)$, and both functions can be computed in time polynomial in the length of $x$. If a problem is polynomial-time solvable, then obviously it is polynomial-time boundable, since we can take $MIN(x)=MAX(x)=OPT(x)$. But the opposite is not necessarily true.

For example, consider the max-min Partition problem, where the input $x$ is a list of positive integers, and the output $y$ is a partition of $x$ into two subsets, and the goal is to maximize the smallest subset sum. It is not polynomial-time solvable unless P=NP, but it is polynomial-time boundable: given an input vector $x$ (a vector of positive integers), we can take $MIN(x)=0$ and $MAX(x)=\sum_i x_i$.

QUESTION: Is there a name for the class of optimization problems that are polynomial-time boundable?

Comment: Let $W(n)$ be the maximum (or minimum) of $OPT(x)$ over all $x$ of length $n$ ─ then it's sufficient for $W(n)$ itself to be bounded by some function computable in time polynomial in $n$. So suppose the problem is not polynomial-time boundable. Either $OPT(x)$ is not computable, or $W(n)$ is, in which case $W$ must not be dominated by any function which can be computed in polynomial time in $n$. This means there must be instances $x$ for which $OPT(x)$ grows extremely quickly relative to the length of $x$. But $OPT$ itself only takes values that $g$ takes, so $g$ also must have this property.

Comment: This seems to imply that if a problem is not polynomial-time boundable, then either the problem is uncomputable, or the value function $g$ cannot be computed in polynomial time.

Comment: @kaya3 do you say that, if $g(x,y)$ can be computed in time polynomial in the length of $x$, then $MAX(x)$ and $MIN(x)$ can be computed in time polynomial in the length of $x$, too?

Comment: The issue is that $MAX$ and $MIN$ can be any functions, so long as they are bounds. They don't necessarily have to have any relationship to the problem, all they need to do is grow sufficiently fast that $g$ can't keep up.

Comment: @kaya3 it is possible that $g(x,y)$ is computable in polynomial time, but $OPT(x)$ is not bounded at all. For example, $g(x,y)=x+y$ and $f(x,y)=True$.

Comment: In that case $g$ can "keep up". But we need to be careful when talking about complexity that the model we're working in doesn't allow e.g. arithmetic with arbitrarily large integers in O(1) time, so typically the domains of $x$ and $y$ are finite (for each particular input size), e.g. in the [Word RAM model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_RAM) integers are $w \sim \log n$ bits wide, in which case $x + y$ is easily bounded by $2^{w+1}$. Note also that if there is no function of $x$ which bounds $g$ in the feasible region then $OPT$ is not well-defined anyway.

Comment: @kaya3 In the Turing Machine model, $g(x,y)=x+y$ can be computed in time linear in the length *of $x$ and $y$*. But, $OPT(x)$ is not polynomial in the length *of $x$ alone*.

Comment: $OPT(x)$ is not defined, since there is no $y$ which maximises $x + y$ for a given $x$.

Comment: @kaya3 exactly. So $MAX(x)$ is not defined too. So, the fact that $g(x,y)$ can be computed in polynomial time, does not imply that $(f,g)$ is polynomial-time boundable.

Comment: I didn't say otherwise ─ I only talked about functions which are computable in polynomial time in the length of $x$. What I said is that if $(f, g)$ is not polynomial-time boundable then $g$ must not be bounded by any polynomial-time-computable function of $x$. Your example of $x + y$ indeed isn't. I don't know what conclusion you want to draw from this, though, because $g(x, y) = x + y$ (where $y$ is unbounded) can't be a profit function for an optimisation problem as described in the question anyway.

Comment: My other point is that if you want to allow $y$ to be unbounded then the problem needs some clarification ─ specifically how are you measuring the time complexity of operations on unbounded integers, and how is the class of optimisation problems defined, since when the domain is infinite, not every $g$ defines an optimisation problem for which $OPT$ exists?

Comment: @kaya3 The upper bound is on $OPT$ - not on $g$. $y$ can be unbounded, but $f(x,y)$ can be True only e.g. when the length of $y$ equals the length of $x$. Since $OPT$ considers only pairs for which $f(x,y)$ is True, it will be bounded.

Comment: Yes, but that's missing the point. You're saying that $OPT$ may be bounded when $g$ is not. I'm saying that if $OPT$ *can't* be bounded as a function of $x$ then neither can $g$. A bound on $g$ would imply a bound on $OPT$.

Comment: @kaya3 Indeed, if $g(x,y)$ can be computed in time polynomial in $x$ alone, then $g(x,y)$ is bounded and so is $OPT(x)$. But this sufficient condition is quite rare, as often $g(x,y)$ will depend on both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: On the contrary, I think it is overwhelmingly common in optimisation problems that $y$ can be bounded in terms of $x$, and hence that $g(x, y)$ can be bounded in terms of $x$. The only counterexample you've given so far is one that does not define an optimisation problem. If we take something like the travelling salesman problem for an example, then $y$ is simply an ordering of the vertices in a graph described by $x$, so it can be described in at most as many bits as $x$ can. Or considering the 0-1 knapsack problem, $y$ is necessarily a subset of the elements of a set described by $x$.

Comment: @kaya3 Ah, OK. In my mind, this restriction went into the function $f$. For example, in TSP, $y$ can be anything, but $f(x,y)$ yields "True" only if $y$ is an ordering of the vertices in a graph described by $x$.